# jQuery validation submitHandler callback issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) to validate my password settings form.

I have below issues with my code.

1. "submitHandler" callback is not hit when I submit the form.
2. "highlight" is hit but has-error is not added into the element which is having the error.

I am submitting the form using click event as seen below:

```
$('#updatePasswordButton').click(function () { 
    postSettings(); 
});
```

### Code

```js
$("#PasswordForm").validate({
  rules: {
    PASSWORD1: {
      required: true,
    },
    PASSWORD2: {
      equalTo: "#PASSWORD1"
    }
  },
  messages: {
    PASSWORD2: "The passwords do not match"
  },
  //TODO yet to highlight the DOM element which has validation error
  highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-control").removeClass("has-error");
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    console.log("submit handle");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name="PasswordForm" id="PasswordForm" method="post">
  <td id="updatePassword">
    <a id="updatePasswordButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-bitbucket" name="setPassword">
      <i id="updatePass" class="demo-icon icon-lock"> </i> &nbsp;UPDATE PASSWORD</a>
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no button or anything that would call `submitHandler()`

Comment: how are you _submitting_ the form?

Comment: I am submitting the form using click event    --------$('#updatePasswordButton').click(function () {
    postSettings();
});

Comment: Can you include enough of the rest of your code to make this a self-contained example? For example: `PASSWORD1`, `PASSWORD2`, and `postSettings()` aren't included in the code snippet.